# In a batch class when deployed to org getting error- Missing return statement required return type

Tags: soql, batch

My requirement is based on mode value passed I need to get the records based on a specific record type value. Below is the sample code. Getting an error- 'Missing return statement required return type'.

This approach is followed so that we dont have 2 batch classes for each mode value passed.

I am not sure what I am missing..Any input would be appreciated.

```
public TestClass(string mode) {
    batchMode = mode;
}

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

    if (batchMode == 'Test1') {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
        [
                SELECT Id
                FROM Account
                WHERE
                RecordType.Id = :TestRecordTypeId
                AND Status_VSG__c = 'Active'
        ]
        );
    }

    if (batchMode == 'Test2') {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
        [
                SELECT Id
                FROM Account
                WHERE
                RecordType.Id = :Test1RecordType
                AND Status_VSG__c = 'Active'
        ]
        );
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet?

Comment: Ah yes ..added it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch `start` method needs a return type. In your case you return type is going as blank return, because both return types are written inside `if` and if the code doesn't enter those then it will need to go to empty `return` which does not throw correct return type (`Database.QueryLocator`)

You can easily use a dynamic SOQL here:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

    String recordTypeId = '';
    if (batchMode == 'Test1') {
        recordTypeId = TestRecordTypeId;
    } else if (batchMode == 'Test2') {
        recordTypeId = Test1RecordType;
    }

    // write a default else too, so that the query does not break if it doesn't enter those ifs.

    String strQuery = 'SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE RecordType.Id =:recordTypeId AND Status_VSG__c = 'Active'';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(strQuery);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nagendra Singh

Answer (score 2):

If you declare a non-void return type, all possible branches in the method must lead to a return statement that returns the declared type (or a valid child type), or throw an uncaught exception.

This means that if you have an if-else chain, every if and else must return a value, if you have a switch, you must return a value in `when else`, otherwise you must have a return statement as the very last line of the method.

For example, you could write your code like this:

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    switch on (batchMode) {
        when 'Test1' {
            return Database.getQueryLocator(
                [
                    SELECT Id
                    FROM Account
                    WHERE
                    RecordType.Id = :TestRecordTypeId
                    AND Status_VSG__c = 'Active'
                ]
            );
        }
        when  'Test2' {
            return Database.getQueryLocator(
                [
                    SELECT Id
                    FROM Account
                    WHERE
                    RecordType.Id = :Test1RecordType
                    AND Status_VSG__c = 'Active'
                ]
            );
        }
        when else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In your code, you wrote `return;`, which is not valid for a non-void return type.

As a side note, it'd probably more efficient to just pass in the record type directly:

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(
        [
            SELECT Id
            FROM Account
            WHERE
            RecordTypeId = :batchRecordTypeId
            AND Status_VSG__c = 'Active'
        ]
    );
}
```